# Databinding Application namespace for attribute bind:font will be ignored

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Im using Realm 4.3.1. While using RealmObject class, the error "`Application namespace for attribute bind:font will be ignored.`" was coming. I tried to remove RealmObject class Im not getting any error from data binding. How can I rectify the error? Thanks in advance.